# Reset Running Total in MS SQL Server based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, window-functions, cumulative-sum

Calculate running total based on the value plus/minus or another table B (that resets the total) in another column by Account and Date.

Example

TableA - 1st Scenario

```
ID     Account  Date         Operation         Qty              Running_Total 
1       A       01/01/2018       plus           10              10
2       A       01/02/2018       plus           20              30 
3       A       01/03/2018       minus           5              20
4       A       01/03/2018       minus           5              20
5       A       01/04/2018       plus           30              50
6       B       01/01/2018       plus           15              15
7       B       01/02/2018       Use Table B    90              40 -- resets 
8       B       01/03/2018       plus           10              50
```

TableA - 2nd Scenario

```
ID     Account  Date         Operation         Qty              Running_Total 
1       A       01/01/2018       plus           10              10
2       A       01/02/2018       plus           20              30 
3       A       01/03/2018       minus           5              20
4       A       01/03/2018       minus           5              20
5       A       01/04/2018       plus           30              50
6       B       01/01/2018       plus           15              15
7       B       01/02/2018       Use Table B    90              40-- resets (currently 80 using below solution)
7       B       01/02/2018       Use Table B    90              40-- resets (currently 80 using below solution)
8       B       01/03/2018       plus           10              50
9       B       01/04/2018       plus           20              75-- new row
10      B       01/04/2018       plus           5               75-- new row
```

TableB

```
ID     Account  Date         RunningQty             
7      B       01/02/2018       40
```

Original Code:

```
select ID, Date, Operation, Total, 
              case when Operation = 'Use Table B' then TableB.RunningTotalQty 
              else
              SUM( case when Operation = 'plus' then  Qty 
                   else case when Operation = 'minus' then -Qty end) 
              OVER (PARTITION BY Account ORDER BY Date)  end
            From TableA A left Join TableB B 
on A.ID = B.ID ...
```

Solution Applied: (@UZI's Code)

```
select
ID, Account, Date, Operation, Qty
   , Running_Total = sum(isnull(RunningQty, Qty * iif(Operation = 'plus', 1, -1))) over (partition by grp order by ID)
from (
select 
    a.*, b.RunningQty, grp = sum(isnull(b.RunningQty, 0)) over (order by a.ID)
from 
    @tableA a
    left join @tableB b on a.ID = b.ID and a.Account = b.Account  and a.Date = b.Date
) t
```

Comment: Thanks updated to MS SQL Server.

Comment: Are you looking to start a new running total from reset value or do you want to subtract that

Comment: Careful. Is it just coincidence that the row in table B has id = 7? Uzi posted a solution on an assumption it was not coincidence. Is the combination of account and date unique? If not, you have problems to overcome.

Comment: @TheGameiswar I need to start from a new running total that comes from another table.

Comment: @SMor Thanks for checking. Table B has id 7 only. There is a one to one match between two tables.

Comment: @SMor - in real data it seems there is no one to one match. I have added another scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Two running totals might solve your issue:

```
declare @tableA table (ID int, Account char(1), Date date, Operation varchar(100), Qty int)
insert into @tableA
values 
(1, 'A', '01/01/2018', 'plus', 10)
, (2, 'A', '01/02/2018', 'plus', 20)
, (3, 'A', '01/03/2018', 'minus', 5)
, (4, 'A', '01/03/2018', 'minus', 5)
, (5, 'A', '01/04/2018', 'plus', 30)
, (6, 'B', '01/01/2018', 'plus', 15)
, (7, 'B', '01/02/2018', 'Use Table B', 90)
, (8, 'B', '01/03/2018', 'plus', 10)

declare @tableB table (ID int, Account char(1), Date date, RunningQty int)
insert into @tableB values (7, 'B', '01/02/2018', 40)

select
    ID, Account, Date, Operation, Qty
    , Running_Total = sum(isnull(RunningQty, Qty * iif(Operation = 'plus', 1, -1))) over (partition by grp order by ID)
from (
    select 
        a.*, b.RunningQty, grp = sum(isnull(b.RunningQty, 0)) over (order by a.ID)
    from 
        @tableA a
        left join @tableB b on a.ID = b.ID and a.Account = b.Account  and a.Date = b.Date
) t
```

Output:

```
ID  Account Date    Operation   Qty Running_Total
-------------------------------------------------
1   A   2018-01-01  plus        10  10
2   A   2018-02-01  plus        20  30
3   A   2018-03-01  minus       5   25
4   A   2018-03-01  minus       5   20
5   A   2018-04-01  plus        30  50
6   B   2018-01-01  plus        15  65
7   B   2018-02-01  Use Table B 90  40
8   B   2018-03-01  plus        10  50
```

EDIT:
You just need to change first running total a bit. `sum() over (order by...)` sums by range by default, so you need to change it to add by rows

```
select
    ID, Account, Date, Operation, Qty
    , Running_Total = sum(isnull(RunningQty, Qty * iif(Operation = 'plus', 1, -1))) over (partition by grp order by ID)
from (
    select 
        a.*, b.RunningQty, grp = sum(isnull(b.RunningQty, 0)) over (order by a.ID rows unbounded preceding)
    from 
        @tableA a
        left join @tableB b on a.ID = b.ID and a.Account = b.Account  and a.Date = b.Date
) t
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. However, if row 7 repeats again it will add 40+40 = 80.                                                                                                                                                                                 
6   B   2018-01-01  plus                       15  65
7   B   2018-02-01  Use Table  B         90  40 -- above code makes this 80
7   B   2018-02-01  Use Table B          90  40 --above code makes this 80
8   B   2018-03-01  plus                       10  50 (Sorry- I am unable to format this in tabular format)

Comment: Where does it repeats? Haven't you said that there's one to one match between tables? Your comment is unclear. Add your data to the question. Show all possible cases and expected output for that data

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I did not notice such case in real data until noe. I have added 2nd scenario.